# Using async functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

So this next function should search in a pre-stored array, inside chrome storage, a certain index equals to the current date:

```
function comparingDates(fn) {
var currentDate = new Date();
var j;
chrome.storage.sync.get("storeDates", function comparing(items) {
        if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
            var arrayDates = items.storeDates;
            j = arrayDates.findIndex(x => x.date == currentDate.getDate());
            console.log(j);
           fn(j);
        };
   });
};
```

With `fn` being the function that will send the corresponding index found to this callback:

```
comparingDates(function (l1) {
        if (!l1) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
           currentDay = l1;
            console.log("succes");
        };
```

the variable `currentDay` is declared before.

After the function is run and the value is sent, takes the condition when `l1` is undefined.

Not knowing full well how to handle async functions is difficult to get a good grasp were the error occurs. And doing some search about it, doesn't provide with good examples for pratical references.

Comment: Well you are missing a closing ) and findIndex returns -1 for not found so if item is in first index it would be an "error" and not found is valid??

Comment: @epascarello when running the code, the console.log(j) pass the correct index. So that part is not a problem i think. anyhow can you show me how you would solved the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what the phrase "takes the condition when `l1` is undefined" means. Do you mean that when you debug it, the `li` argument is `undefined`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah, exactly that. Sorry for not knowing how to express myself.

Comment: So your problem is not what you have above, it is code that is not shown....

Comment: No problem. How are you identifying `l1` is `undefined`? Do you have a `console.log(l1)` in there somewhere? It's hard for us, of course, since we don't have your data.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan when passing 'l1' from comparingDates, i do a check of the variable with '!l1'. if it returns truth  i get a 'console.log("error")'. if not truth it assign l1 to currentDay.

Comment: Yeah, I can read your code. But "truth" is in the eye of the beholder. In the case of JavaScript, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, and a number of other things evaluate to false when used in a condition. It is important for us to know the exact value of the `l1` variable. Add a `console.log(l1)` at the top of the function you pass to `comparingDates` (in your second code block).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i see the problem them, the index value pass is 0 this time

Answer (score 1):

findIndex returns -1 for not found so if you were to do

```
if (-1) console.log("Is Truthy")
```

You would get the console line. And if the item is in the first index (aka 0) than the check would also fail.

You should be checking for -1, not truthy.

```
  comparingDates(function (l1) {
    if (l1===-1) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      currentDay = l1;
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
```

---

And if you are saying this

```
  var l1;
  comparingDates(function (l1) {
    if (l1===-1) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      currentDay = l1;
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
  console.log(l1) <-- is undefined
```

Than you have the problem where you order a pizza and soon as you hang up the phone, you try to eat the pizza. The code after the function does not sit and wait for the callback to run. That is why we have the callback to wait for the order to be delivered. The logic needs to be done there.

Comment: LOL @ pizza analogy. It's really good except for the fact that in this case, because you're not waiting asynchronously on an HTTP request or database query or anything like that, it's not quite like ordering pizza because the pizza delivery guy controls when your pizza arrives, but here you control when you call the function to resolve the value, right? It would be more like having your own pizza in the oven and wondering why it's not on the table yet when you forgot to take it out of the oven.

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get("storeDates"` is the delivery guy in his beat up ford escort with missing exhaust pipes but has nice rims with spinners.